# Bipartite matching in graph

Tags: c++, graph-theory, bipartite

I have the following code which is an implementation of BPM (bipartite matching, from graph theory)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using  namespace std;
#define M 128
#define N 128
bool graph[M][N];
bool seen[N];
int matchL[M],matchR[N];
int n=4;
int m=4;

bool bpm(int u){

    for(int v=0;v<n;v++) if(graph[u][u])
    {
                if (seen[v]) continue;
                seen[v]=true;
                if(matchR[v] <0 || bpm(matchR[v])){
                    matchL[u]=v;
                    matchR[v]=u;
                    return true;
                }
    }

    return false;

}

int main(){

    graph[0][1]=1;
    graph[0][3]=1;
    graph[1][3]=1;
    graph[0][2]=1;
     memset(matchL,-1,sizeof(matchL));
     memset(matchR,-1,sizeof(matchR));
     int cnt=0;
     // memset(seen,0,sizeof(seen));
     for(int i=0;i<m;i++){

        memset(seen,0,sizeof(seen));
          if(bpm(i)) cnt++;

     }
     cout<<cnt<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The definition of `cnt` and the purpose of this code are given below.

> Given a bipartite graph represented as an m-by-n matrix, where `graph[i][j]` is `true` iff there is an edge from pigeon `i` to hole `j`, computes the maximum number of pigeons that can find a hole (one per pigeon) and an optimal assignment.

- `graph[m][n]`, `matchL[n]`, `matchR[m]` and `seen[m]` are global arrays.
- `main()` initializes `matchL[]` and `matchR[]` to `-1` in all components.
- `main()` does a loop over all pigeons `i` and in each iteration

  - clears `seen[]` to `0` in all components
  - calls `bpm(i)` and increments the `maxflow` counter
  - `bpm(i)` returns `true` iff pigeon `i` can be assigned a hole
- `cnt` contains the number of happy pigeons.

In my case, `cnt`'s value is output as `0`. Does this graph algorithm work correctly or have I made some error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your initialization is faulty or this condition in `bpm()` is faulty:

```
       if (graph[u][u])
```

There is no element of `graph` on the diagonal which is set `true`, so `bpm()` always fails completely.  It is also not clear why you'd be needing to test the diagonal alone.  Maybe it should be `if (graph[u][v])`, or maybe something else.

(Your indentation leaves somewhat to be desired; it is extremely aconventional to put an `if` condition such as this on the same line as a `for` loop control.  Incidentally, the initialization of `matchL` and `matchR` only works on 2's-complement machines.)